# How to make a "tolerance" in milliseconds in javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, time

I'm creating a piano tiles game from javascript using canvas, I have a case where the user has to press a button in an exact location and time. I have to give the user a 100ms tolerance so if the user pressed the button 100ms earlier or later it still counts.

A solution would be appreciated.

[image]

The yellow and blue blocks are the tiles so the user has to press the keys at the exact time and location of the tiles

Comment: px/sec and frames/sec don't have anything to do with each other.

Comment: It's notable, that `requestAnimationFrame` doesn't always fire exactly at the rate of 60 fps, sometimes it can jump over three or even four steps, depending on what other scripts, OS and other applications are doing.

Comment: yeah just remembered that frames aren't pixels, silly me

Answer (score 0):

Usually, it is best not to mix representation with the underlying logic.

You need to represent the task (note to be played/button pressed) along with the time (or time offset when do you expect it. Then once the button is pressed compare if the current time matches the expected time.

here is a toy example that may give you ideas

```js
var startTime = 0;

$(document).ready(function(){


    $('#butt').on('click', function(){


    var curTime = new Date().getTime();
    if (startTime === 0)
    {
        startTime = new Date().getTime()
       $('#log').val('Now try pressing it exactly every second')
    }
    else
    {
  
       $('#log').val('You were off by ' + (curTime - startTime - 1000)+'ms');
       startTime = curTime
   
    }

   })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="butt">
Press me once a second
</button>
<textarea id='log' rows=10 cols=50>Click button to start</textarea>
```

Comment: I see, I can use this to check if the user pressed the button too late. But how can I get the expected time for the early button press?

Comment: A negative value in the log indicates an early button press

Comment: yeah, but you did expect it in 1 second right? but in my case, I don't. And I could speed up the tiles depending on the scores. I'm adding an example image to be clear about how the game works, sorry. Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: You need to share your code and show what works and what does not. You should not expect a complete solution on a complex task from SO